# How to have the same SSL certificate install on 2 server?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I'm trying to migrate a wordpress website from AWS to GCP.

I need a load balancer on GCP's side and it will take a while for it to provision.
How can I have the SSL install on GCP's server without any disruption on AWS's side?

Is there a recommended way to migrate with minimum downtime?

Comment: Are you using the google managed certificates for the load balancer or you have your own certificates?

Comment: @ElsaPorico Hi, Intend to use Google managed certificate.

Comment: Mmmm those certificates rely on the DNS records so, as you mention, while those records are validated (which implies you modify the DNS to redirect to GCP and only have this record) and the certificate is provisioned the downtime can be of about 10-15 minutes if everything goes well. For now I don't have any other ideas to minimize the downtime to a couple of minutes :/

Comment: Thanks @ElsaPorico Does using own certificate help to reduce the downtime?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that in order to use the Google Managed certificates, Google may need to validate you own the domain for the certificates to be provisioned and that why it needs you to add the LB from GCP in A record. On the other hand if you have your own certificate, the LB does not need any type of validation and everything will be configured. Once you add you're own certificate and the LB is ready (you wait a couple of minutes), in your DNS you add the GCP LB's IP and remove the one from your AWS site. Your clients will not notice the change.

Comment: Anyway, do not shutdown your AWS site immediately and wait maybe 1 or 2 days. This is because the old record that pointed to your AWS sited is kept in cache in other DNS servers so is a good idea to wait so the these DNS servers can get the new IP from the GCP side

Comment: Thanks @ElsaPorico Really appreciate it. If to use own certificate in this case, after the migration, I would like to switch to Google managed certificate, will downtime be expected too?

Answer (score 1):

With respect, don't do this.

Instead, wait til your new vendor has provisioned the load balancer. Then put the TLS certificate into the load balancer. Then, and only then, switch your DNS records to point to the new load balancer.

The stopgap step of putting your TLS certs on the servers behind the load balancer is a mess of trouble, and unnecessary if you can delay your DNS cutover for a day or so, running your old system for that time.

Comment: Thanks. I may not have understood correctly. How can I setup the load balancer without specifying the TLS certificate? I don't see an option to skip that step on GCP's console.